# Copy of a hard disk, error during the mount because of luks

Tags: mount, encryption, disk, luks, testdisk

A few weeks ago I encrypted an external hard drive with luks and the header bugged. I can still open the drive with my password but it shows me an empty folder. So I made a copy of the whole disk with a .dd (after opening it). And when I try to mount the .dd, same empty folder. I have a "lost+found" folder and when I do e2fsck with it I get this:

```
e2fsck -b 32768 'lost+found' 
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
e2fsck: Is a directory while trying to open lost+found

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

When I open the disk and do e2fsck on the device, I get this:

```
sudo e2fsck luks-adf42aa0-9542-416b-93b2-44e0fd12fa32
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open luks-adf42aa0-9542-416b-93b2-44e0fd12fa32

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found an atari partition table in luks-adf42aa0-9542-416b-93b2-44e0fd12fa32
```

Do you have any idea what to do?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: How did the header get "bugged"?  If the header is corrupted or missing on a luks volume, you won't be able to decrypt or access any data unless you made a backup.  Making a copy won't help in this situation because you'd just copy whatever problem from the original.

Comment: @Nmath It's a maxtor hard drive and I had a software to open a password protected part on windows. When I switched to Linux, I deleted this partition and encrypted it with Luks following a tutorial. And I got a message that the header was bugged and since then, every time I enter the password, it opens but I have an empty folder. Is there really no way to recover the data? But when I make the copy afterwards with dd, I'm supposed to have kept everything even if it's encrypted, right?

Comment: dd copies bit-for-bit indiscriminately, so the destination will be exactly like the source.

Comment: Yes so what can I do ? Is there a compagny that can found again my data ?

Comment: You can bring it to a data recovery specialist. They charge a small fortune and based on your description, it's very unlikely they are going to find anything.  Without the header and the ability to decrypt, everything will be scrambled by encryption.

Comment: Ok thank you @Nmath ! Cheers